# jquery ajax form with securimage captcha

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to put securimage's captcha but i am having problem with my codes. it doesnt read the conditions that checks if the captcha is correct but just saves data and ignores the captcha. here are my jquery code that lets me save data on my database without reloading

```
(function() {

    if($('#contactform').length) {

        var $form = $('#contactform'),
        $loader = '<img src="images/preloader.gif" alt="Loading..." />';
        $form.append('<div class="hidden" id="contact_form_responce">');

        var $response = $('#contact_form_responce');
        $response.append('<p></p>');

        $form.submit(function(e){

            $response.find('p').html($loader);

            $.post("php/contact-send.php", $("#contactform").serialize(), function(response) {

                $response.find('img').remove();
                $response.find('p').removeClass().addClass('success type-2');
                $response.find('p').append('Your email has been sent!');
                $form.find('input:not(input[type="submit"], button), textarea, select').val('').attr( 'checked', false );
                $response.delay(1500).hide(400);



            });

            e.preventDefault();


        });             
    }
})();
/* end Contact Form */
```

here is my php code that processes my data

```
require_once "../includes/database.php";
session_start();
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pcf/securimage/securimage.php';
    $securimage = new Securimage();
    if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {  
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Captcha!')</script>";
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.open('contact.php?alink=c','_self')</script>";
        exit;
    }
    $cname=$_POST['name'];
    $cemail=$_POST['email'];
    $cmessage=$_POST['message'];
    $date=date("Y-m-d");    
            $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (sendername,senderemail,message,datesent) VALUES (:name,:email,:message,:date)";
            $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
            $qry->execute(array(':name'=>$cname,':email'=>$cemail,':message'=>$cmessage,':date'=>$date));
```

Comment: whats the result if you're var_dump this $securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code'])

Comment: nothing.. it just ignores the condition. T_T

Comment: did you try to var_dump? it should supposed to print something like null, false or true. Also, check your error logs, it helps you in debugging but i suggest do var_dump( $securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) ). Find out what it returns.